# gdb exits with : Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction for a c c++ program compiled with gcc / intel_mkl / gfortran -mavx

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, gfortran, intel-mkl

I have a c and c++ mixed large code that is compiled into static libraries.  I call functions from simgms static library from the given program -
main.cpp is simple but the executable doesn't run and throws a run-time error Illegal instruction. gdb exits from main() in the very first line -inside main.

Searching about the problem hinted that this could be due to gcc version or incompatibility of libraries with intel_mkl. If anyone had encountered with similar issues, suggestions welcome. Thanks!

```
 #include "simgms_scf.h"

 #define c_version

 #include <iostream>

    int main()

    {


            double ex[] = {130.7093200, 23.8088610,  6.4436083, 5.0331513,  1.1695961,  0.3803890, 3.42525091, 0.62391373, 0.16885540 };

            double cs[] = { 0.15432897, 0.53532814, 0.44463454,     -0.09996723, 0.39951283, 0.70011547, 0.15591627, 0.60768372, 0.39195739};
            double *cp = cs, *cd = cs, *cf = cs, *cg = cs, *ch = cs, *ci = cs;
                   .
                   .
                   .

                    simgms_scf_c(ex, numBFunc, numOccAlpha, 0, atomCoordinates, nuclearCharges, 0);


            return 0;

}
```

(This program worked without a problem on windows/Visual Studio. I ported and changed the code to work on linux64)

This is the noteworthy step in building the static library simgms

```
    %.o: ../%.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: G++ Compiler'

 g++ -Wall -mavx -g -O -O1 -std=c++11 -lgfortran  -L/opt/shared/sw/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/5.3.0-rhel6/lib64 -libstdc -libsupc++ -libtsan -libubsan -libvtv -libquadmath -libgcc_s -libgcj  -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_mc -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_gf_ilp64 -lmkl_avx -lmkl_lapack95_lp64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core  -L/home/..mypath/simint/lib -lsimint -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mkl/include  -I/opt/shared/sw/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/5.3.0-rhel6/include -I/home/..mypath/simint/include -I/home/..mypath/include/simint/debug  -DDEBUG -DMKL_ILP64 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -c -o "$@" "$<"
 @echo 'Finished building: $<'
 @echo ' '

%.o: ../%.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC Compiler'
 gcc -Wall -mavx -g -O -O1  -lgfortran  -L/opt/shared/sw/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/5.3.0-rhel6/lib64 -libstdc -libsupc++ -libtsan -libubsan -libvtv -libquadmath -libgcc_s -libgcj  -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_mc -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_gf_ilp64 -lmkl_avx -lmkl_lapack95_lp64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core  -L/home/..mypath/simint/lib -lsimint -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mkl/include  -I/opt/shared/sw/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/5.3.0-rhel6/include -I/home/..mypath/simint/include -I/home/..mypath/include/simint/debug  -DDEBUG -DMKL_ILP64 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -c -o "$@" "$<"
 @echo 'Finished building: 
 $<'        @echo ' '
```

Here is how I create the main executable from main.cpp

```
 gcc -Wall -mavx -g -O -O1 -o main -lgfortran ../main.cpp -L/home/..mypath/Debug -lsimgms -L/home/..mypath/simint -lsimint -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_mc -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_gf_ilp64 -lmkl_avx -lmkl_lapack95_lp64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core   -I/home/..mypath/simint -I/home/..mypath/include -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mkl/include  -I/opt/shared/sw/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/5.3.0-rhel6/include -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

Here is the gdb trace (What I could get)

```
 (gdb) bt main
 No stack.
 (gdb) b main
 Breakpoint 1 at 0x401906: file ../main.cpp, line 12.
 (gdb) run
 Starting program: /home/...mypah/simgms/Debug/main 

 Breakpoint 1, main () at ../main.cpp:12
 12              {
 (gdb) step
 15                      double ex[] = {130.7093200, 23.8088610,  6.4436083, 5.0331513,  1.1695961,  0.3803890, 3.42525091, 0.62391373, 0.16885540 };
 (gdb) step

 Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
 main () at ../main.cpp:15
 15                      double ex[] = {130.7093200, 23.8088610,  6.4436083, 5.0331513,  1.1695961,  0.3803890, 3.42525091, 0.62391373, 0.16885540 };
```

Dump of assembler code

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000401906 in main ()
(gdb) info line 1
Line number 1 is out of range for "<built-in>".
(gdb) disassemble /m

Dump of assembler code for function main:
=> 0x0000000000401906 <+0>:     sub    $0x1d8,%rsp
0x000000000040190d <+7>:     vmovsd 0x5b613(%rip),%xmm1        # 0x45cf28
0x0000000000401915 <+15>:    vmovsd %xmm1,0x180(%rsp)
0x000000000040191e <+24>:    vmovsd 0x5b60a(%rip),%xmm2        # 0x45cf30
0x0000000000401926 <+32>:    vmovsd %xmm2,0x188(%rsp)
0x000000000040192f <+41>:    vmovsd 0x5b601(%rip),%xmm3        # 0x45cf38
0x0000000000401937 <+49>:    vmovsd %xmm3,0x190(%rsp)
0x0000000000401940 <+58>:    vmovsd 0x5b5f8(%rip),%xmm4        # 0x45cf40
0x0000000000401948 <+66>:    vmovsd %xmm4,0x198(%rsp)
0x0000000000401951 <+75>:    vmovsd 0x5b5ef(%rip),%xmm5        # 0x45cf48
0x0000000000401959 <+83>:    vmovsd %xmm5,0x1a0(%rsp)
0x0000000000401962 <+92>:    vmovsd 0x5b5e6(%rip),%xmm6        # 0x45cf50
0x000000000040196a <+100>:   vmovsd %xmm6,0x1a8(%rsp)
0x0000000000401973 <+109>:   vmovsd 0x5b5dd(%rip),%xmm7        # 0x45cf58
0x000000000040197b <+117>:   vmovsd %xmm7,0x1b0(%rsp)
0x0000000000401984 <+126>:   vmovsd 0x5b5d4(%rip),%xmm1        # 0x45cf60
0x000000000040198c <+134>:   vmovsd %xmm1,0x1b8(%rsp)
0x0000000000401995 <+143>:   vmovsd 0x5b5cb(%rip),%xmm2        # 0x45cf68
0x000000000040199d <+151>:   vmovsd %xmm2,0x1c0(%rsp)
0x00000000004019a6 <+160>:   vmovsd 0x5b5c2(%rip),%xmm3        # 0x45cf70
0x00000000004019ae <+168>:   vmovsd %xmm3,0x130(%rsp)
0x00000000004019b7 <+177>:   vmovsd 0x5b5b9(%rip),%xmm4        # 0x45cf78
0x00000000004019bf <+185>:   vmovsd %xmm4,0x138(%rsp)
0x00000000004019c8 <+194>:   vmovsd 0x5b5b0(%rip),%xmm5        # 0x45cf80
0x00000000004019d0 <+202>:   vmovsd %xmm5,0x140(%rsp)
0x00000000004019d9 <+211>:   vmovsd 0x5b5a7(%rip),%xmm6        # 0x45cf88
0x00000000004019e1 <+219>:   vmovsd %xmm6,0x148(%rsp)
0x00000000004019ea <+228>:   vmovsd 0x5b59e(%rip),%xmm7        # 0x45cf90
0x00000000004019f2 <+236>:   vmovsd %xmm7,0x150(%rsp)
0x00000000004019fb <+245>:   vmovsd 0x5b595(%rip),%xmm1        # 0x45cf98
0x0000000000401a03 <+253>:   vmovsd %xmm1,0x158(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a0c <+262>:   vmovsd 0x5b58c(%rip),%xmm2        # 0x45cfa0
0x0000000000401a14 <+270>:   vmovsd %xmm2,0x160(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a1d <+279>:   vmovsd 0x5b583(%rip),%xmm3        # 0x45cfa8
0x0000000000401a25 <+287>:   vmovsd %xmm3,0x168(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a2e <+296>:   vmovsd 0x5b57a(%rip),%xmm4        # 0x45cfb0
0x0000000000401a36 <+304>:   vmovsd %xmm4,0x170(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a3f <+313>:   movq   $0x1,0x100(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a4b <+325>:   movq   $0x1,0x108(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a57 <+337>:   movq   $0x1,0x110(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a63 <+349>:   movq   $0x2,0x118(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a6f <+361>:   movq   $0x2,0x120(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a7b <+373>:   movq   $0x2,0x128(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a87 <+385>:   movq   $0x1,0xd0(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a93 <+397>:   movq   $0x1,0xd8(%rsp)
0x0000000000401a9f <+409>:   movq   $0x4,0xe0(%rsp)
0x0000000000401aab <+421>:   movq   $0x4,0xe8(%rsp)
0x0000000000401ab7 <+433>:   movq   $0x7,0xf0(%rsp)
0x0000000000401ac3 <+445>:   movq   $0x7,0xf8(%rsp)
0x0000000000401acf <+457>:   movq   $0x1,0xa0(%rsp)
0x0000000000401adb <+469>:   movq   $0x1,0xa8(%rsp)
0x0000000000401ae7 <+481>:   movq   $0x2,0xb0(%rsp)
0x0000000000401af3 <+493>:   movq   $0x2,0xb8(%rsp)
0x0000000000401aff <+505>:   movq   $0x1,0xc0(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b0b <+517>:   movq   $0x1,0xc8(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b17 <+529>:   movq   $0xd,0x70(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b20 <+538>:   movq   $0x0,0x78(%rsp)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
0x0000000000401b29 <+547>:   movq   $0x0,0x80(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b35 <+559>:   movq   $0x0,0x88(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b41 <+571>:   movq   $0x0,0x90(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b4d <+583>:   movq   $0x0,0x98(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b59 <+595>:   movq   $0x3,0x40(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b62 <+604>:   movq   $0x3,0x48(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b6b <+613>:   movq   $0x3,0x50(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b74 <+622>:   movq   $0x3,0x58(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b7d <+631>:   movq   $0x3,0x60(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b86 <+640>:   movq   $0x3,0x68(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b8f <+649>:   vxorpd %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
0x0000000000401b93 <+653>:   vmovsd %xmm0,0x10(%rsp)
0x0000000000401b99 <+659>:   vmovsd 0x5b417(%rip),%xmm5        # 0x45cfb8
0x0000000000401ba1 <+667>:   vmovsd %xmm5,0x18(%rsp)
0x0000000000401ba7 <+673>:   vmovsd %xmm0,0x20(%rsp)
0x0000000000401bad <+679>:   vmovsd 0x5b40b(%rip),%xmm6        # 0x45cfc0
0x0000000000401bb5 <+687>:   vmovsd %xmm6,0x28(%rsp)
0x0000000000401bbb <+693>:   vmovsd 0x5b405(%rip),%xmm7        # 0x45cfc8
0x0000000000401bc3 <+701>:   vmovsd %xmm7,0x30(%rsp)
0x0000000000401bc9 <+707>:   vmovsd %xmm0,0x38(%rsp)
0x0000000000401bcf <+713>:   vmovsd 0x5b3f9(%rip),%xmm1        # 0x45cfd0
0x0000000000401bd7 <+721>:   vmovsd %xmm1,(%rsp)
0x0000000000401bdc <+726>:   vmovsd 0x5b3f4(%rip),%xmm2        # 0x45cfd8
0x0000000000401be4 <+734>:   vmovsd %xmm2,0x8(%rsp)
0x0000000000401bea <+740>:   lea    0x130(%rsp),%rsi
0x0000000000401bf2 <+748>:   push   %rsp
0x0000000000401bf3 <+749>:   lea    0x18(%rsp),%rax
0x0000000000401bf8 <+754>:   push   %rax
0x0000000000401bf9 <+755>:   pushq  $0x0
0x0000000000401bfb <+757>:   pushq  $0x4
0x0000000000401bfd <+759>:   pushq  $0x6
0x0000000000401bff <+761>:   pushq  $0x1
0x0000000000401c01 <+763>:   pushq  $0x6
 0x0000000000401c03 <+765>:   lea    0xa8(%rsp),%rax
0x0000000000401c0b <+773>:   push   %rax
0x0000000000401c0c <+774>:   lea    0x80(%rsp),%rax
0x0000000000401c14 <+782>:   push   %rax
0x0000000000401c15 <+783>:   lea    0xe8(%rsp),%rax
0x0000000000401c1d <+791>:   push   %rax
0x0000000000401c1e <+792>:   lea    0x150(%rsp),%rax
0x0000000000401c26 <+800>:   push   %rax
0x0000000000401c27 <+801>:   lea    0x128(%rsp),%rax
0x0000000000401c2f <+809>:   push   %rax
0x0000000000401c30 <+810>:   push   %rsi
0x0000000000401c31 <+811>:   push   %rsi
0x0000000000401c32 <+812>:   mov    %rsi,%r9
0x0000000000401c35 <+815>:   mov    %rsi,%r8
0x0000000000401c38 <+818>:   mov    %rsi,%rcx
0x0000000000401c3b <+821>:   mov    %rsi,%rdx
0x0000000000401c3e <+824>:   lea    0x1f0(%rsp),%rdi
0x0000000000401c46 <+832>:   callq  0x401caa <simgms_scf_c>
0x0000000000401c4b <+837>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000401c50 <+842>:   add    $0x248,%rsp
0x0000000000401c57 <+849>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

(gdb)

Assembler dump after crashing:

```
 Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x000000000040190d in main () 
(gdb) disassemble /m
Dump of assembler code for function main:
    0x0000000000401906 <+0>:     sub    rsp,0x1d8
  => 0x000000000040190d <+7>:     vmovsd xmm1,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b613]        # 0x45cf28
   0x0000000000401915 <+15>:    vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x180],xmm1
   0x000000000040191e <+24>:    vmovsd xmm2,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b60a]        # 0x45cf30
   0x0000000000401926 <+32>:    vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x188],xmm2
0x000000000040192f <+41>:    vmovsd xmm3,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b601]        # 0x45cf38
0x0000000000401937 <+49>:    vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x190],xmm3
0x0000000000401940 <+58>:    vmovsd xmm4,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b5f8]        # 0x45cf40
0x0000000000401948 <+66>:    vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x198],xmm4
0x0000000000401951 <+75>:    vmovsd xmm5,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b5ef]        # 0x45cf48
0x0000000000401959 <+83>:    vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x1a0],xmm5
0x0000000000401962 <+92>:    vmovsd xmm6,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b5e6]        # 0x45cf50
0x000000000040196a <+100>:   vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x1a8],xmm6
0x0000000000401973 <+109>:   vmovsd xmm7,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b5dd]        # 0x45cf58
0x000000000040197b <+117>:   vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x1b0],xmm7
0x0000000000401984 <+126>:   vmovsd xmm1,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b5d4]        # 0x45cf60
0x000000000040198c <+134>:   vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x1b8],xmm1
0x0000000000401995 <+143>:   vmovsd xmm2,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b5cb]        # 0x45cf68
0x000000000040199d <+151>:   vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x1c0],xmm2
0x00000000004019a6 <+160>:   vmovsd xmm3,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b5c2]        # 0x45cf70
0x00000000004019ae <+168>:   vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x130],xmm3 
0x00000000004019b7 <+177>:   vmovsd xmm4,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b5b9]        # 0x45cf78
0x00000000004019bf <+185>:   vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x138],xmm4
0x00000000004019c8 <+194>:   vmovsd xmm5,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b5b0]        # 0x45cf80
0x00000000004019d0 <+202>:   vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x140],xmm5
0x00000000004019d9 <+211>:   vmovsd xmm6,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b5a7]        # 0x45cf88
0x00000000004019e1 <+219>:   vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x148],xmm6
0x00000000004019ea <+228>:   vmovsd xmm7,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b59e]        # 0x45cf90
0x00000000004019f2 <+236>:   vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x150],xmm7
0x00000000004019fb <+245>:   vmovsd xmm1,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b595]        # 0x45cf98
0x0000000000401a03 <+253>:   vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp+0x158],xmm1
0x0000000000401a0c <+262>:   vmovsd xmm2,QWORD PTR [rip+0x5b58c]        # 0x45cfa0
```

Comment: Try running under GDB and look at the backtrace (with debugging symbols) and the disassembly of the crash site. If that doesn't help, report back what you see.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I edited the question with the GDB trace.

Comment: what about the disassembly? Only the part around the faulting instruction (marked with `=>`) is relevant.

Comment: Added the assembler dump. I'm not sure if that is what you meant though.

Comment: I meant from the crash side.  You pasted the assembly from the breakpoint (start of main).

Comment: I haven't used GDB this way before. So I got part of the assembly just after it crashed now. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 4):

You program crashes with `SIGILL` on the very first AVX instruction (`vmovsd`).  This means that your hardware, hypervisor, or kernel does not support AVX.  If your hardware supports AVX, you can likely get this to work by software upgrades (hypervisor and kernel).  If you use virtualization, you may have to instruct the hypervisor to pass through AVX support to the guest, too.  (Recent enough kernels will automatically support AVX.)

Comment: Thanks! Removing -mavx everywhere I was able to get an output (still it throws an Illegal instruction at the end before exiting) But It goes past the function call.